# Python C extension importer how to use import lock

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-3.7

**Background**

I'm building an [importer](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-importer) to encrypt my code. When compiling, I encrypt the code object in `pyc` files. When loading, I use this customized importer to decrypt the code object before execution.

Since my code is bundled in zip format, I decided to modify `zipimporter` from the builtin [zipimport](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/zipimport.html) package by adding the decrypt logic into it.

I'm using Python 3.7

**Problem**

I modified the [zimpimport.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/zipimport.c) and make it into C extension. The encrypt & decrypt process works fine but I started to see `ImportError` & `AttributeError`. For example:

```
"""module: test.py"""
class Foo:

    def bar():
        pass

foo = Foo()

// Import Error: can not import name 'foo' from test 
// Attribute Error: foo has no attribute bar
```

When server starts, this error only occurs during the first few minutes randomly. So I suspect that it's a multithreading problem and it's caused by a thread seeing a partially initialized module object.

**What I tried**

After checking the origin c code, the implementation for loading a module is:

```
mod = PyImport_AddModuleObject(fullname);
// ... some code
mod = PyImport_ExecCodeModuleObject(fullname, code, modpath, NULL);
```

It first add module to `sys.modules`, then execute some c code and execute the module code at last. If another thread read the `sys.modules` before it finishes executing module code, it can get the `ImportError` and `AttributeError`.

I just copy the original implementation and it doesn't use import lock. I guess it's handled by interpreter on outer level and I have to explicitly use import lock. So I wrap the code block with the import lock as following:

```
#include "import.h"
_PyImport_AcquireLock();
// wrapped code block
_PyImport_ReleaseLock();
```

**My Question**

After adding import lock, the error still happens. I'm not familiar with python c api. Have I used the lock in a correct way? Are there other possible reasons that can cause this error?

**Code**

To test, put the following files in same folder:

- [zzimporter.c](https://gist.github.com/CtheSky/64d76ddc3196023cf66df5f8ff232a41) lock added in func `zipimport_zipimporter_load_module_impl`
- [zzimporter.h](https://gist.github.com/CtheSky/65c6f7acbf2a4c9c6bb57757f2ec66dc)
- [setup.py](https://gist.github.com/CtheSky/1b18efb4fdfb0d3efddd56a7e7718dcd)

Run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` and it will generate `zzimporter.so`. And it works just like the buit-in zipimport module.

Comment: `test` is always a bad name to use because there's an existing module called `test` so you can end up importing the wrong thing by accident

Comment: It's for demonstration purpose only, just want to hide some  unnecessary infos. But it's a good advice, thanks.

Comment: @CtheSky: You do certainly seem to be all about hiding things.  Do you know that it’s pretty trivial to reconstitute an unencrypted `.pyc` from the resulting module object?

Comment: @DavisHerring That's true. To prevent that, I use embedding python, so there's no available module object (or at least not very easy to get). And pyinstaller also provides [this option](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#encrypting-python-bytecode).